# ES6 Functions Syntax?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to call my namespaced store:

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions('Modal', [
        'toggleActive',
    ]),
    close: () => {
        this.toggleActive();
    }
```

Which results in the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleActive' of undefined
```

Doing the following works:

```
close: function() {
    this.toggleActive();
}
```

How can I use ES6 function syntax with vue/vuex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using arrow functions. Arrow functions *close over* the `this` in the context where they're defined, instead of having it set when they're called like `function` functions. E.g.:

```
// Whatever `this` means here
var o = {
    foo: () => {
        // ...is what `this` means here when `foo` is called
    }
};
```

You probably just want to use method syntax instead:

```
methods: {
    // (I'm using a simple method for toggleActive just for clarity; if you're
    // transpiling with something that understands rest notation for
    // objects, your `mapActions` thing is probably fine *provided* that
    // the functions it creates aren't also arrow functions
    toggleActive() {
        // ...
    },
    close() {
        ths.toggleActive();
    }
};
```

Note that this is subject to all the usual `this` stuff [described in this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback).

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at your link and your edited answer, I'm still left confused though as arrow functions - with "this" inside should refer to the vuex namespaced state?

Comment: @panthro: Why would they do that? Again, they *close over* `this`, exactly like closing over other variables. (If you don't see my `foo` example above, hit refresh.)

Comment: Ive checked your foo example, ah so "this" means "this" outside of the class?

Comment: @panthro: I can't comment on code I can't see, you haven't provided much context in the question, just the partial inside of an object initializer. But whatever `this` is in the scope where that object initializer is, is what `this` will be when `close` is called.